# How do I change language with toggle switch?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use in-page translation script with toggle switch. I failed in my attempts. That's why I opened this issue.
My translation codes:

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.switcher .selected').click(function() {if(!(jQuery('.switcher .option').is(':visible'))) {jQuery('.switcher .option').stop(true,true).delay(100).slideDown(500);jQuery('.switcher .selected a').toggleClass('open')}});
    jQuery('.switcher .option').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {var options = jQuery('.switcher .option');if(options.is(':visible'))options.scrollTop(options.scrollTop() - e.originalEvent.wheelDelta);return false;});
    jQuery('body').not('.switcher').mousedown(function(e) {if(jQuery('.switcher .option').is(':visible') && e.target != jQuery('.switcher .option').get(0)) {jQuery('.switcher .option').stop(true,true).delay(100).slideUp(500);jQuery('.switcher .selected a').toggleClass('open')}});
</script>
<li style="display:none" id="google_translate_element2"></li>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit2() {new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'tr',autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element2');}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GTranslateGetCurrentLang() {var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?googtrans=([^;]*)(;|$)');return keyValue ? keyValue[2].split('/')[2] : null;}
    function GTranslateFireEvent(element,event){try{if(document.createEventObject){var evt=document.createEventObject();element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)}else{var evt=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');evt.initEvent(event,true,true);element.dispatchEvent(evt)}}catch(e){}}
    function doGTranslate(lang_pair){if(lang_pair.value)lang_pair=lang_pair.value;if(lang_pair=='')return;var lang=lang_pair.split('|')[1];if(GTranslateGetCurrentLang() == null && lang == lang_pair.split('|')[0])return;var teCombo;var sel=document.getElementsByTagName('select');for(var i=0;i<sel.length;i++)if(sel[i].className=='goog-te-combo')teCombo=sel[i];if(document.getElementById('google_translate_element2')==null||document.getElementById('google_translate_element2').innerHTML.length==0||teCombo.length==0||teCombo.innerHTML.length==0){setTimeout(function(){doGTranslate(lang_pair)},500)}else{teCombo.value=lang;GTranslateFireEvent(teCombo,'change');GTranslateFireEvent(teCombo,'change')}}
    if(GTranslateGetCurrentLang() != null)jQuery(document).ready(function() {jQuery('div.switcher div.selected a').html(jQuery('div.switcher div.option').find('img[alt="'+GTranslateGetCurrentLang()+'"]').parent().html());});
</script>
```

The toggle switches [I'm thinking of using](https://codepen.io/TorabRamin/pen/mqrBBj).
My last try:

```html
    <div class="switch">
        <input id="language-toggle" class="check-toggle check-toggle-round-flat" type="checkbox">
        <label for="language-toggle"></label>
        <span class="on"><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('tr|tr');jQuery('div.switcher div.selected a').html(jQuery(this).html());return false;"title="English" class="nturl"><img src="http://www.websanati.com/images/turkish.png" height="18" width="22" alt="english" /></a></span>
        <span class="off"><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('tr|en');jQuery('div.switcher div.selected a').html(jQuery(this).html());return false;"title="English" class="nturl"><img src="http://www.websanati.com/images/english.png" height="18" width="22" alt="english" /></a></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: `height="18" width="22"` on an `a` element? unsafe inline `on*` attributes? Ugh... Rather use the respective CSS and JS file or tag.

Comment: Why so many `<script type="text/javascript">`? you need only one.

Comment: Instead of always repeating `jQuery` use `jQuery($ => { /* DOM ready and $ alias in scope */ });` and inside the *function body* `$` as an alias for jQuery.

Comment: @Bukr3j please format your code to have some help here. It's really unreadable the way it is (minified)

Comment: @wiwi You are right. Sorry.

Comment: i can't fix @wiwi